# Creating Custom Login Form Where Password Field is Dropdown Menu

Tags: login, user-access

First, I want to name that I think purchasing MemberPress and some customization of their login form would make this possible. However, we are not planning to fully utilize anything else the MemberPress plugin offers, so I am trying to determine if this is possible via another (less costly) way first.

I would like to create a login screen where the password field is listed first and is actually comprised of about 100 options or so.

Then, the username field is listed second and is unique to the user (as normal).

Finally, I need to be able to update the username/passwords via CSV upload monthly on the backend, as frontend registration is not allowed.

Like this: http://member.txdar.org/

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: A password as a dropdown menu, what?! That is a **BIG** no no, please don't do that. You just ask for user data to be stolen this way, this is not a good, secure idea at all. Also uploading passwords as CSV, what?! Everything about this screams a bad idea, and please steal all my users data.

Comment: There will be no personal information asked for / no user input requested on the site (not even a name or real username) post login... it's simply just to grant permission to the "members" site. Right now there is no password at all, so this is a step up. If we don't use something like this, then it will be left without any kind of login. It's how the whole organization handles the issue... not necessarily up to me. It's a very nontraditional use (I know that), but the way the site is used (to hide some pages from the general public), there isn't a big risk is UN/PW uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty. Welcome .

Let's quickly go over your idea. From what I understand, you want to create 100 users with dynamically changing passwords over time. Not to tamper with the security of a password and its basic functionality.

**Roughly, here is how I would do it...**
Without touching the core functionality of WordPress's login system. However, you would likely need to source a plugin to import and export user info from WordPress's backend in a CSV format.

**Within your functions.php file for WordPress**

```php
// Get the usernames from the DB.
function get_usernames() {
    global $wpdb;
    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users");
    $usernames = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $usernames[] = $user->user_login;
    }
    return $usernames;
}
```

```php
// Build a select element with the usernames as options.
function get_usernames_dropdown() {
    $usernames = get_usernames();
    $dropdown = '<select name="usernames">';
    foreach ($usernames as $username) {
        $dropdown .= '<option value="' . $username . '">' . $username . '</option>';
    }
    $dropdown .= '</select>';
    return $dropdown;
}
```

```php
// Add the select element as shortcode.
// Usage: [usernames_dropdown]
function usernames_dropdown_shortcode() {
    return get_usernames_dropdown();
}
add_shortcode('usernames_dropdown', 'usernames_dropdown_shortcode');
```

To round it off, you'd build your login form like any other, but instead of a text field for a username, you'd use the dropdown field instead. This IMO is the least indestructive and hacky way.